# Induction issue

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

I have defined a type of trees, together with a `fusion` operation as follows:

```
open nat

inductive tree : Type
| lf : tree
| nd : tree -> nat -> tree -> tree

open tree

def fusion : tree -> tree -> tree
| lf t2 := t2
| (nd l1 x1 r1) lf := (nd l1 x1 r1)
| (nd l1 x1 r1) (nd l2 x2 r2) :=
    if x1 <= x2
    then nd (fusion r1 (nd l2 x2 r2)) x1 l1
    else nd (fusion (nd l1 x1 r1) r2) x2 l2
```

Then, I have a counting function which returns the number of occurrences of a given integer in a tree:

```
def occ : nat -> tree -> nat
| _ lf := 0
| y (nd g x d) := (occ y g) + (occ y d) + (if x = y then 1 else 0)
```

I want to prove that `(occ x (fusion t1 t2)) = (occ x t1) + (occ x t2)`, but in the course of the proof, I have a problem as I don't know how to deal with the given induction hypotheses.

So far, I have come up to this:

```
theorem q5 : ∀ (x : ℕ) (t1 t2 : tree),
    (occ x (fusion t1 t2)) = (occ x t1) + (occ x t2) :=
begin
    intros x t1 t2,
    induction t1 with g1 x1 d1 _ ih1,
    simp [fusion, occ],
    induction t2 with g2 x2 d2 _ ih2,
    simp [fusion, occ],
    by_cases x1 <= x2,
    simp [fusion, h, occ],
    rw ih1,
    simp [occ, fusion, h],
    simp [occ, fusion, h],
end
```

but I'm desperately stuck. The ih deals with `fusion d1 (nd g2 x2 d2))` while I want something about `fusion (nd g1 x1 d1) d2`.

I'll gladly welcome any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach to this question is to prove using the equation compiler using the same pattern match that you defined the function `fusion` with

```
theorem q5 (x : ℕ) : ∀ (t1 t2 : tree),
    (occ x (fusion t1 t2)) = (occ x t1) + (occ x t2)
| lf t2 := by simp [fusion, occ]
| (nd l1 x1 r1) lf := by simp [fusion, occ]
| (nd l1 x1 r1) (nd l2 x2 r2) := 
begin
  simp only [fusion, occ],
  by_cases hx12 : x1 ≤ x2,
  { rw [if_pos hx12],
    simp only [fusion, occ],
    rw q5,
    simp [occ] },
  { rw if_neg hx12,
    simp only [fusion, occ],
    rw q5,
    simp [occ] }
end
```

An alternative approach is

```
theorem q5 : ∀ (x : ℕ) (t1 t2 : tree),
    (occ x (fusion t1 t2)) = (occ x t1) + (occ x t2) :=
begin
  intros x t1,
  induction t1 with g1 x1 d1 _ ih1,
  { simp [fusion, occ] },
  { assume t2,
    induction t2 with g2 x2 d2 _ ih2,
    simp [fusion, occ],
    by_cases x1 <= x2,
    { simp [fusion, h, occ, ih1] },
    { simp [occ, fusion, h, ih2] } },
end
```

The problem with your approach is that `rw ih2` is possible at the end of your proof but generates two difficult to prove subgoals due to the hypotheses before the induction hypothesis.

A solution to this is to change the first induction hypothesis. There is no `intro t2` before the induction in my second proof. That way the induction hypothesis is stronger for the first induction, because starts with `∀ t2`.

Whenever you do induction on a variable `t2`, every hypothesis mentioning `t2` is automatically added as an assumption before your induction hypothesis.

In your cases, the induction hypotheses for the first induction mention `t2`,
so you end up with an awkward induction hypothesis for the second hypothesis.

However, my induction hypotheses for the first induction start with `∀ t2`, so they are not about my local constant `t2`, so they are not added to the induction hypothesis for the second induction, so I have a more useful induction hypothesis.

There is usually no downside to giving yourself the most powerful induction hypothesis like this, by generalizing it `∀ t2`. This is why it is the default way that the equation compiler generates induction hypotheses.

Comment: Once again, you save me. Thank for your very clear explanations about the correct use of quantification in induction hypotheses.